# How to locate the bottom widget absolutely?

Tags: flutter

Please refer to the Widget `Text("HERE")` and corresponding ScreenShot below.
When a keyboard appears from the bottom of device, the Widget `Text("HERE")` relatively moved to upper-side, hence I should care about overflow of whole widget size as well as size of user devices.

How can I locate this Widget absolutely, or should I always make all things (widget) `scrollable` to corresponds to any devices and also to avoid overflow problem ?

```
Stack(
 children:[
  ,//omit
  const Align(
     alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
     child: Text("HERE"),
  )
 ]
)
```

[image]

Comment: are you using Stack just for this Text?

Comment: you can try setting the value resizeToAvoidBottomInset to true in Scaffold widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yes, I am

Comment: try ` Mahendra Raj methods and I think you can use Spacer widget before this Text

Comment: Wrapping it in a SingleChildScroll widget could help

Comment: @MahendraRaj　Oh, thanks and it worked ! As to my latter question, generally we developer do not know what kind size of devices user is gonna pick or how small size of devices are gonna be developed in the future. How should I care about overflow problem ?

Comment: @SugiuraY you can explore flutter_screenutil package or the hard way would be to use FittedBox which doesn't guarantee you to which size it gets shrunk or expanded.

Comment: @MahendraRaj Apologies for my late reply, and the package was really helpful for me and thanks for your advise again !

Comment: @Hunter Books thanks for your comment and it worked as well !

Comment: @MahendraRaj I believe that the value of  `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` should be `false` right ?

Answer (score 1):

first, make sure you constrained your `Scaffold` widget to the full-screen height, with `MediaQuery`:

```
ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    ),
    child: Scaffold(// your screen code),
  ),
```

then wrap your `Text` with a `Positioned` widget, then set the bottom property to 0 or the value you want to bottom with:

```
    // ...
     child: Stack(
       children:[
     Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
       child: Text("HERE"),
     )         
    ]
   )
```

now even the keyboard is on, the screen will not resize and the `Text` widget will stay forcelly in the bottom of screen.

Answer (score 1):

just add this line in `Scaffold`

```
Scaffold( 
   ...
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset : ture
);
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?